# One DB One App or One DB Multiple App

Tags: sql-server, database, optimization, database-design, database-migration

Though this question has been asked and answered multiple times still I need some answer.

My team has already developed one ASP.NET app which is being used by hundreds of organization. Currently we are using one application one database model but since we provide frequent updates and changes that include both front end and back end we are having hard time in managing hundreds of database.

So, We have thought on moving to  Single database for all application.
I want to know your opinion on which one is better and why ? (NOTE: Majority of our customer are within country)

- One application one database (current model)
- One database for all application
- One database for limited number of application (5 or 10 or 50)

Data in one of the major table can cross 500 rows per day for one organization.

We have our own dedicated server.

Comment: If you decide to go for shared database, then SQL Server 2016 Row-Level Security could help you -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx

Comment: Another option is one database, multiple schemas